# How did they encipher this?

Tags: cipher

I'm confused by this.

> ...The sender of a message might use plaintext words for which there are prearranged secret equivalents so that the sentence "SALLY ARRIVES ON EVENING TRAIN" might mean "STRIKE IS ON." 
>   <sub>Source: World Book Dictionary, page 97</sub>

*How* did they encipher that? I'm still wondering.

Comment: Is that a cipher? Can't it be something like "The bird is in the nest" to say "The target is in position"?

Comment: The key is `there are prearranged secret equivalents` - so there is a prior key exchange of innocuous words and their equivalent hidden meaning.

Comment: @Saeïdryl yes, it is in "Codes and Ciphers"

Comment: @Phylyp "prearranged secret equivalents" doesn't necessarily implies a "logical" cipher. That can totally be "Sally arrives" > "Strike" / "On" > "Is" / ... (I agree that would be a terrible cipher)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a cypher but a coded message.

"Prearranged secret equivalent" means that this message corresponds to one and only one unencoded message. Thus, if "Sally arrives on evening train" means "Strike is on", there is no way to change it to make it say instead "Strike is postponed".

This kind of messages was used a lot during the WWII on [Radio Londres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Londres#Coded_messages).